# Disable PrtSc + B instareboot "feature"

Tags: reboot, sysrq

How can I disable this: [Magic SysRq key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

The keyboard layout on my Lenovo Thinkpad X230 is such, that the keys <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are right next to eachother, as are the <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> keys and it is very simple to typo <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> when I wanted to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, at which time the computer instantly reboots and I loose all my work.

This is a terrible feature and as I can see I can only turn it off by recompiling the kernel. Is there another way I can disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing

```
sudo nano /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

And writing a 0 to it will allow the sysrq keys to be disabled during normal operation. However, it's worth noting, that until that file is read during the boot process the sysrq keys will still be available (but by the time you log on, it will not be)

Comment: Will this setting persist accross reboots, or do I have to set something in /etc/sysctl.conf ?

Comment: It should be persistent. Also, you can use the command `sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=0` if you don't want to edit the file manually